# How to join worker node in existing cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, kubeadm, kubelet

I was facing some issues while joining worker node in existing cluster.
Please find below the details of my scenario.
I've Created a HA clusters with **4 master and 3 worker**.
I removed 1 master node.
Removed node was not a part of cluster now and reset was successful.
Now joining the removed node as worker node in existing cluster.

I'm firing below command

```
kubeadm join --token giify2.4i6n2jmc7v50c8st 192.168.230.207:6443 --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:dd431e6e19db45672add3ab0f0b711da29f1894231dbeb10d823ad833b2f6e1b
```

*In above command - 192.168.230.207 is cluster IP*

Result of above command

```
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING Service-Docker]: docker service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable docker.service'
    [WARNING IsDockerSystemdCheck]: detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd". Please follow the guide at https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/cri/
    [WARNING FileExisting-tc]: tc not found in system path
    [WARNING Service-Kubelet]: kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service'
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
error execution phase preflight: unable to fetch the kubeadm-config ConfigMap: failed to get config map: Get https://192.168.230.206:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kubeadm-config: dial tcp 192.168.230.206:6443: connect: connection refused
```

Already tried Steps

1. ted this file(`kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml`) using kubeadm patch and removed references of removed node("192.168.230.206")
2. We are using external etcd so checked member list to confirm removed node is not a part of etcd now. Fired below command `etcdctl --endpoints=https://cluster-ip --ca-file=/etc/etcd/pki/ca.pem --cert-file=/etc/etcd/pki/client.pem --key-file=/etc/etcd/pki/client-key.pem member list`

Can someone please help me resolve this issue as I'm not able to join this node?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @P Ekambaram answer, I assume that you probably have completely dispose of all redundant data from previous `kubeadm join` setup.

1. Remove cluster entries via `kubeadm` command on worker node: `kubeadm reset`;
2. Wipe all redundant data residing on worker node: `rm -rf /etc/kubernetes; rm -rf ~/.kube`;
3. Try to re-join worker node.

Answer (score 1):

Use these instructions one after another to completely remove all old installation on worker node.....

```
kubeadm reset

systemctl stop kubelet

systemctl stop docker

rm -rf /var/lib/cni/

rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet/*

rm -rf /etc/cni/

ifconfig cni0 down

ifconfig flannel.1 down

ifconfig docker0 down

ip link delete cni0

ip link delete flannel.1

systemctl start docker.service

yum remove kubeadm kubectl kubelet kubernetes-cni kube*

yum autoremove

rm -rf ~/.kube
```

then reinstall using

```
yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl

reboot

systemctl start docker && systemctl enable docker
systemctl start kubelet && systemctl enable kubelet
```

then use kubeadm join command

Comment: Please explain why you expect this to help.

Comment: They help removing footprints from previous installation.

Answer (score 1):

`kubeadm join` try to reach 192.168.230.206 whereas new IP is 192.168.230.207.

In addition to change in cm kubeadm-config, you may change your cluster IP address (cluster.server) in this configmap

```
kubectl edit cm -n kube-public cluster-info
```

Answer (score 0):

fix these problems and run join command

1. docker service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable docker.service'
2. detected "cgroupfs" as the Docker cgroup driver. The recommended driver is "systemd".
3. kubelet service is not enabled, please run 'systemctl enable kubelet.service

Comment: I've already tried all this steps but didn't worked for me. Looks like some configuration has been preserved in active master node while removing another master but I'm not able to locate those thing apart from config map which i have mentioned in above details.

Comment: are you able to run docker and kubelet on the woker node?

Comment: yes both are running. kubelet service automatically restart after 10s as RestartSec property is set to 10s. I'm adding this as a worker node than why join command redirected to this IP 192.168.230.206 and looking for kube config.

Comment: why do you restart kubelet? it shouldnt be restarted every 10s

Comment: Changed configuration but didn't worked, now kubelet only start when it fails.

Comment: did you change the driver to systemd?

Comment: [preflight] Running pre-flight checks 
 [WARNING FileExisting-tc]: tc not found in system path 
[preflight] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[preflight] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -oyaml'
error execution phase preflight: unable to fetch the kubeadm-config ConfigMap: failed to get config map: Get https://192.168.230.206:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kubeadm-config: dial tcp 192.168.230.206:6443: connect: connection refused

Comment: Looks like some foot prints from previous install are still left on that worker node.  Hence you are not able to join it

Comment: That's what I'm assuming, Not sure how to track that part. Can you please help me in identifying that part?